# ARM A9 GIC order of completion of interrupts

Tags: arm, interrupt

Reading the  "ARM® Generic Interrupt Controller Architecture version 1.0 Architecture Specification" I read that "For nested interrupts, the order of interrupt completion must be the reverse of the order of interrupt acknowledgment. That is, the order of writes to the ICCEOIR must be the reverse of the order of reads from the ICCIAR.". My first problem is that the specification does not specify the behavior when an not in reverse order write to ICCEOIR happens, nor does it classifies it as UNPREDICTABLE. What would be the problem if I do this?

However, I found that regardless of the order of acknowledgment, when I write  ICCEOIR with the id of an active interrupt, that interrupt becomes inactive. I am doing this on a Xilinx Zynq-7000. Should I just expect this on this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, see earlier in the same section of the GIC specification:

> Writing to this register causes the GIC to change the status of the
>   identified interrupt:
>
> - to inactive, if it was active
> - to pending, if it was active and pending.

Expecting this to happen irrespective of the order of acknowledgment seems reasonable, regardless of what other effects out-of-order completion might have.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I reached the same conclusion, and since I don't plan to port my system anytime soon I'll follow your advice. However, the GICv2 specification already classifies the behavior of out-of-order completions as UNPREDICTABLE, so maybe it was just something they missed in the v1 specification.